# How to pass values without using onChange() in HTML but in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, onchange

I know this is a simple question. But I couldn't find a way to overcome this issue. All I want is this. I have a drop-down created using *select* element & when user selecting a city from that drop-down it should be able to pass that selected value to console ( console.log() ). But I am able to pass very first selected value only. I found a way to pass values to console using  onChange() with *select* element as following code.

### HTML

```
<select id="comboA" onchange="getComboA(this)">
    <option value="">Select combo</option>
    <option value="Value1">Text1</option>
    <option value="Value2">Text2</option>
    <option value="Value3">Text3</option>
</select>
```

### JS

```
function getComboA(selectObject) {
    var value = selectObject.value;  
    console.log(value);
}
```

But in my case, the whole procedure needs to be code without using onChange() in HTML. Because I have to get user inputs from WordPress form and need to make separate JS file from the form. So, I can't add or change HTML code of the form. My code is below.

### HTML code

---

```
<select name="city" class="city" id="city-selection">
    <option selected="selected" value="">Select City</option>
    <option value="City 1">City 1</option>
    <option value="City 2">City 2</option>
    <option value="City 3">City 3</option>
    <option value="City 4">City 4</option>
    <option value="City 5">City 5</option>
    <option value="City 6">City 6</option>
    <option value="City 7">City 7</option>
</select>
```

The JS code I used is below.

## JS code

---

```
var cityVal = document.getElementById("city-selection");
var cityCon = cityVal.options[cityVal.selectedIndex].text;
console.log(cityCon);
```

Please help me with this issue.

Comment: what is the issue with using the `eventlistener` to listen for a `change` evenet?

Comment: You can use a onchange listener in the JS. Just get your element like in your 2nd example and add the listener to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look on this fiddle:
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kxpL48e1/2/)

```
const selectCites = document.getElementById("city-selection");

selectCites.addEventListener("change", function(e) {
e.preventDefault();

const { srcElement } = e;
const { selectedOptions } = srcElement;

for (let i = 0; i < selectedOptions.length; i++) {
console.log(selectedOptions[i].value);
console.log(selectedOptions[i].text);
}
})
```

Basically I added a event listener on the select and wait for any changes and then I loop through the selectedOptions in a case you have more than one.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for your help. Your little effort helps me a lot with my issue.

Answer (score 2):

```js
const selectElement = document.querySelector('#city-selection');
const changeHandler = (ev) => {
  console.log('Change!', ev.target.value);
}
selectElement.addEventListener('change', changeHandler);
```

```html
<select name="city" class="city" id="city-selection">
    <option selected="selected" value="">Select City</option>
    <option value="City 1">City 1</option>
    <option value="City 2">City 2</option>
    <option value="City 3">City 3</option>
    <option value="City 4">City 4</option>
    <option value="City 5">City 5</option>
    <option value="City 6">City 6</option>
    <option value="City 7">City 7</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add the `EventListener` to listen for a `change`-event:

```js
document.addEventListener("change", function() {
  var cityVal = document.getElementById("city-selection");
  var cityCon = cityVal.options[cityVal.selectedIndex].text;
  console.log(cityCon);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can register an external event listener to respond to the `change` event like this:

```js
document.querySelector('select[name="city"]').addEventListener('change',function(e){
  console.log( 'value: %s - Text: %s',this.value, this.options[ this.options.selectedIndex ].text )
});
```

```html
<select name="city" class="city" id="city-selection">
    <option selected="selected" value="">Select City</option>
    <option value="City 1">City 1</option>
    <option value="City 2">City 2</option>
    <option value="City 3">City 3</option>
    <option value="City 4">City 4</option>
    <option value="City 5">City 5</option>
    <option value="City 6">City 6</option>
    <option value="City 7">City 7</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

you cant use target property. like this :

```
const myCombo = document.getELementByID("myCombo");
myCombo.addEventListener("change" , (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.value)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Almost all the best alternatives has been given, you can either use pure javascript or jquery

Say this is your HTML codes for Cities in Tanzania:

```
    <select name="city" class="city" id="city-selection">
        <option selected="selected" value="">Select City</option>
        <option value="dar">Dar es Salaam </option>
        <option value="mbeya">Mbeya</option>
        <option value="mwanza">Mwanza</option>
        <option value="dodoma">Dodoma</option>
        <option value="arusha">Arusha</option>
        <option value="morogoro">Morogoro</option>
        <option value="tanga">Tanga</option>
        <option value="zanzibar">Zanzibar City</option>
        <option value="kigoma">Kigoma</option>
    </select>
```

So your pure javascript can be:

```js
     document.getElementById('city-selection').addEventListener('change', function() {
         let selectedCity = this.value;
         console.log(selectedCity);
    });
```

Jquery:

```js
         $('#city-selection').on('change', function() {
            let selectedCity = $(this).val();
            //let selectedCity = this.value; this will also do the same 
            //as the above declaration format
            console.log(selectedCity);
         });
```

I hope this can be of help to you